# How to create Dynamic factory in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

In my project i have to create dynamic factory in angular js with dynamic factory name like below

```
  function createDynamicFactory(modId) {
     return myModule.factory(modId + '-existingService', function (existingService) {
        return existingService(modId);
    }); 
}
```

I want to get new factory with dynamic name , when i called this function. unfortunately this is not working. how can i achieve this? and how to inject in my controller or in directive dynamically?

Comment: Can you offer more insight than "this is not working"?

Comment: @Marc: hi marc, i mean, if i put the break point at above return statement(return existingService(modId);) the control is not reaching to that break point,though i called *createDynamicFactory* function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can annotate your service generator like this. It takes the module and extension and then annotates a dependency on the "echo" service (just an example service I defined to echo back text and log it to the console) so the generated service can use it:

```
makeService = function(module, identifier) {
    module.factory(identifier+'-service', ['echo', function(echo) {
            return {
                run: function(msg) {
                    return echo.echo(identifier + ": " + msg);
                }
            };
        }]);
    };
```

Then you can make a few dynamic services:

```
makeService(app, 'ex1');
makeService(app, 'ex2');
```

Finally, there are two ways to inject. If you know your convention you can pass it in with the annotation as the ext1 is shown. Otherwise, just get an instance of the $injector and grab it that way.

```
app.controller("myController", ['ex1-service', 
                                '$injector',
                                '$scope',
                                function(service, $injector, $scope) {
    $scope.service1 = service.run('injected.');   
    $scope.service2 = $injector.get('ex2-service').run('dynamically injected');
}]);
```

Here is the full working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/QM52v/1/

Updated: if you want to create the service dynamically after the module is initialized, it's a few slight changes. Instead of trying to register the module, simply return an annotated array. The first parameters are the dependencies and the last is the function to register:

```
makeService = function(identifier) {
    return ['echo', function(echo) {
        console.log("in service factory");
            return {
                run: function(msg) {
                    return echo.echo(identifier + ": " + msg);
                }
            };
        }];
    };
```

Then you get a reference to the array and call instantiate on the $injector to wire it up with dependencies:

```
var fn = makeService('ex2');
$scope.service2 = $injector.instantiate(fn).run('dynamically injected');
```

Here's the fiddle for that version: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/G98JD/2/

Comment: Hi jeremy thanks for the reply, in my case i am calling makeService function dynamically. I updated your plunker here http://jsfiddle.net/G98JD/. it was throwing Unknown provider error

Comment: In that case you just need to define your service and use $injector.instantiate to wire it up. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/G98JD/1/

Comment: instead of looking for dependencies, can I declare these dynamically created factory/services as dependencies, just like $http and other. Ex: `App.controller('TestCtrl, ['$http', 'dynamicFactory', function ($http, dynamicFactory) { ... } ])` ? In my case dynamically factory/service name will not change. Basically I've a provider which create other factories/services dynamically.