# dynamic factory angularjs (resolve data to controller)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I read an answer about "dynamic factory" from [How to create Dynamic factory in Angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733661/how-to-create-dynamic-factory-in-angular-js)

It works great but some additional conditions required for my project make me tired.

conditions are simple.

1. There is a button that trigger dynamic directive element. From now we call the original background's scope 'ParentScope' and directive's 'ChildScope'.
2. At the same time, 'ParentScope' dynamically make factory named "ex2-service".
3. This directive's controller needs to inject "ex2-service".

above simple example is http://jsfiddle.net/chaht01/QM52v/29/

jscode below

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.service("echo", function() {
    return {
        echo: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            return msg;
        }
    };
}), makeService = function(module, identifier) {
    module.factory(identifier+'-service', ['echo', function(echo) {
        return {
            run: function(msg) {
                return echo.echo(identifier + ": " + msg);
            }
        };
    }]);
};

makeService(app, 'ex1');

app.controller("myController", ['ex1-service', 
                            '$injector',
                            '$scope',
                            function(service, $injector, $scope) {
    $scope.service1 = service.run('injected.');
    $scope.test = function(){
        $scope.isReady = true;
        makeService(app, 'ex2');
    }
}]).controller("child",['ex2-service','$scope',function(service,$scope){
    $scope.service2 = service.run('dynamically injected')
}])
```

when I click button, get error like

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provide: ex2-serviceProvider <- ex2-service
```

how can I solve this problem??

Comment: What you are trying to do is "hot" addition of a factory to the `$injector` cache. In other words you are adding the factory after the config phase, during the run phase of the app. I would rather not show how to do "hot" addition of providers because then StackOverflow will fill up with questions from people misusing that technique. Can you **really** describe a use case for "hot" config changes? You can always do "hot" injection with the `$injector` service.

Comment: The question you quoted gives an example of that.  -- "In that case you just need to define your service and use `$injector.instantiate` to wire it up."  [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/G98JD/1/)